# What is wrong in "森田さんは新開発の薬をもって病気を克服した"?

Tags: grammar, usage, jlpt

> 最新の医療技術をもってすれば、人はさらに寿命を伸ばせるだろう。  OK
>
> 森田さんは**人一倍の努力**をもって病気を克服したのである。  OK
> 森田さんは**新開発の薬**をもって病気を克服したのである。  KO

My textbook* says the third sentence is not OK, but I don't understand why, as it seems to respect the usage rules explained in the same textbook.
Can someone enlighten me?

*:スリーエーネットワーク新完全マスター文法日本語能力試験N1

Comment: All sentences sound more or less atypical to me. Mind sharing what your textbook says?

Comment: As an aside, the phrase `をもって` (in the sense of "by", "with", "on the grounds of" etc.) is usually written in kana only, or if you must use kanji, it should be `を以て`.

Comment: @broccoliforest: Edited question to include requested information.

Comment: @blutorange: I was my error, fixed.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Thank you, but what I meant was, doesn't your textbook say something about definition of "もって"? Plus, are you sure it writes exactly "人一倍努力をもって"?

Comment: @broccoliforest: I had forgotten の thanks! The textbook says: 〜を手段としてある行為をする。硬い言い方。日常・具体的な道具や方法などには使わない。

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Well, your examples have changed so much lol. No problem, that's just the way I thought.

Comment: Hmm...as your textbook, it supposed to be wrong because 薬 is a real, physical instrument. But as far as I searched a corpus, they do use.

Comment: @broccoliforest: Might be indeed! "具体的". Could you please merge this to your answer? Thanks!

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I did it. And my last example was temporarily removed as I noticed I mixed it up with でもって, until I'd come up with a new one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「をもって」 couldn't be used with the tools which directly takes effect, but with **methods** or something helps achieve purpose **where the linkage is perceived abstractly**.

Your third example,

> 森田さんは新開発の薬をもって病気を克服したのである。

means *the new medicine cured his/her disease*, thus unacceptable. In contrast,

> 森田さんは人一倍の努力をもって病気を克服したのである。

only mentions how his/her state of mind helped when Morita overcame the disease. (At least, the effort couldn't attack pathogens, according to modern understanding.)